# I wrote a game and get a compile error which I don't understand

Tags: c++

I wrote a program and get the following compiler messages:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\c++ projekte\erebos_2\erebos_2\mainplayer.h(8): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Name'
1>d:\c++ projekte\erebos_2\erebos_2\mainplayer.h(8): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>d:\c++ projekte\erebos_2\erebos_2\mainplayer.h(8): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>d:\c++ projekte\erebos_2\erebos_2\main.cpp(11): error C2144: Syntaxfehler: 'int' sollte auf ';' folgen
1>  Mainplayer.cpp
1>d:\c++ projekte\erebos_2\erebos_2\mainplayer.h(8): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Name'
1>d:\c++ projekte\erebos_2\erebos_2\mainplayer.h(8): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>d:\c++ projekte\erebos_2\erebos_2\mainplayer.h(8): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void MainMenu:: createMenu()
{
    int typed;
    system("cls");
    cout << "1) Start" << endl;
    cout << "2) Hilfe" << endl;
    cout << "3) Credits" << endl;
    cout << "4) Beenden" << endl;
    cin >> typed;
    if(typed == 1)
    {
        //main.mainGame();
        cout << "...still..." << endl;
    }
}
```

---

```
    class MainMenu
    {
    public:
        void createMenu();
    };
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "MainPlayer.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int health;
int xp;
int lvl;
int gold;
string Name = "Namenloser";

void Mainplayer:: showData()
{
    cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << Name << endl;
    cout << "Leben: " << health << "/100" << endl;
    cout << "Erfahrung: " << xp << "/" << lvl*10 << endl;
    cout << "Level: " << lvl << "/50" << endl;
    cout << "Gold: " << gold << endl;
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
}
```

---

```
class Mainplayer
{
    public:
        int health;
        int xp;
        int lvl;
        int gold;
        string Name;
        void showData();
};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "MainPlayer.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void maingame()

int main()
{
    system("title EREBOS 2");
    Mainplayer MainChar; 
    MainMenu menu;
    menu.createMenu();
    MainChar.showData();
}
```

Comment: [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: `#include <string>` in MainPlayer.h + write `std::string` instead of `string`

Comment: I translated the question from German to English, but I couldn't translate the compiler errors. Though I guess my previous comment can be the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MainPlayer.h`, you use the type `string` which was not included until then. Include `<string>` in `MainPlayer.h`.

Also, in the header, specify the full type with `std::string` instead of just `string`.

There are more errors in your program, e.g. in `MainPlayer.cpp` you declare global variables, but I guess you wanted to initialize your *member variables*. That should happen in a *constructor*.

---

<sub>**German:** In `MainPlayer.h` benutzt du den Typ `string`, der bis dahin noch nicht included wurde. Include also `<string>` in diesem Header. Außerdem musst du (im Header) `std::string` statt `string` schreiben. Es gibt weitere Fehler, z.B. deklarierst du globale Variablen in `MainPlayer.cpp`, obwohl du vermutlich die *Membervariablen* initialisieren wolltest. Dies sollte in einem *Konstruktor* geschehen.</sub>

Comment: In `MainPlayer.h`, verwenden Sie den Typ `string`, die bis dahin nicht enthalten war. Include `<string>` in `MainPlayer.h`.  Außerdem geben Sie den vollständigen Typ mit std :: string statt nur Schnur.  Es gibt mehrere Fehler in Ihrem Programm, beispielsweise in MainPlayer.cpp erklären Sie globale Variablen, aber ich denke, Sie Ihre Mitgliedsvariablen initialisieren wollen. Das sollte in einem Konstruktor passieren.    ---- (Translated using Google Translate)

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks for helping, but I already included German version (I'm native speaker...) ;)

Comment: I hit Send just when you edited your answer. By the way, is the translated version at least readable? :)

Comment: _@leemes_  Also the automated german translation doesn't serve very well. That kinda lingo is hardly correct german.

Comment: @ForceBru Well, some words are really strange. But mainly because we sometimes prefer to use the original English words, slightly adopted to German style word endings / letters, like "Membervariablen", "includen", "string" (in favor of "Mitgliedsvariablen", "enthalten", "Schnur", respectively, which don't make much sense whatsoever in a programming context)

Comment: @leemes _"letters, like "Membervariablen", "includen", "Konstruktor""_ All of them wrong, sorry.

Comment: @ForceBru LOL! _"Sie Ihre Mitgliedsvariablen initialisieren wollen"_ And even more ridiculous; _"Außerdem geben Sie den vollständigen Typ mit std :: string statt nur Schnur."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I don't understand German at all except basic greetings. So, I can't judge if it's funny or not, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What do you mean with *wrong*? Most of them *are* German words. Some aren't, but they are used by German programmers. And my answer is not automatically translated; I translated it by hand.

Comment: @leemes Just making _german words_ (which they aren't actually), doesn't make that a valid german translation. Guten Tag!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What the heck are you complaining about? They are words used by German teachers, programmers, books, internet sites, ... Why should I use other words, which make it harder to understand, when answering to a German programmer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See [this example](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstruktoren_und_Destruktoren). Also, feel free to provide a better translation of my answer.

Comment: Leemes can you maybe help me with another problem ? same program but other error......for more informations: